# Why kubernetes keeps pods in Error/Completed status - preemptible nodes, GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an issue with my GKE cluster. I am using two node pools: secondary - with standard set of highmen-n1 nodes, and primary - with preemptible highmem-n1 nodes. Issue is that I have many pods in Error/Completed status which are not cleared by k8s, all ran on preemptible set. THESE PODS ARE NOT JOBS.

GKE documentation says that:
"Preemptible VMs are Compute Engine VM instances that are priced lower than standard VMs and provide no guarantee of availability. Preemptible VMs offer similar functionality to Spot VMs, but only last up to 24 hours after creation."

"When Compute Engine needs to reclaim the resources used by preemptible VMs, a preemption notice is sent to GKE. Preemptible VMs terminate 30 seconds after receiving a termination notice."
Ref: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms

And from the kubernetes documentation:
"For failed Pods, the API objects remain in the cluster's API until a human or controller process explicitly removes them.

The Pod garbage collector (PodGC), which is a controller in the control plane, cleans up terminated Pods (with a phase of Succeeded or Failed), when the number of Pods exceeds the configured threshold (determined by terminated-pod-gc-threshold in the kube-controller-manager). This avoids a resource leak as Pods are created and terminated over time."
Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection

So, from my understanding every 24 hours this set of nodes is changing, so it kills all the pods running on them and depending on graceful shutdown pods are ending up in Completed or Error state. Nevertheless, kubernetes is not clearing or removing them, so I have tons of pods in mentioned statuses in my cluster, which is not expected at all.

I am attaching screenshots for reference.
[image: Pods in Error/Completed State]
Example `kubectl describe pod` output:
Status:           Failed
Reason:           Terminated
Message:          Pod was terminated in response to imminent node shutdown.

Apart from that, no events, logs, etc.

GKE version:
1.24.7-gke.900

Both Node pools versions:
1.24.5-gke.600

Did anyone encounter such issue or knows what's going on there? Is there solution to clear it in a different way than creating some script and running it periodically?

I tried digging in into GKE logs, but I couldn't find anything. I also tried to look for the answers in docs, but I've failed.

Answer (score 2):

The given commands does not work for me.

I have created a few manifests that you can apply in your cluster to automatically delete the Pods matching the criteria with a kubernetes CronJob.

https://github.com/tyriis/i-see-dead-pods

this is working for me

```
kubectl get pods \
          --all-namespaces \
          -o go-template \
          --template='{{range .items}}{{printf "%s %s %s\n" .metadata.namespace .metadata.name .status.message}}{{end}}' \
          | grep "Pod was terminated in response to imminent node shutdown." \
          | awk '{print $1, $2}' \
          | xargs -r -n2 kubectl delete pod -n
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this command. I also looked up your manifests, but in the end, I've implemented it as a cronjob in our pipelines, since it will be easier to manage for multiple environments. Once again, big thanks for that! <3

Comment: @Withel I would be interested in what is missing, I also accept PRs and would push this further to have a re-usable source. I was facing the same problem since long time and didn't find a suited solution in previous iterations.

Comment: Being honest I'm not sure if anything is missing. Before getting deeper look (and eventually trying deploying the manifest) with my team we think it's easier to manage from the CI/CD pipe than deploying into each of the environments :)

Answer (score 1):

While using the node pool with Preemptible mode the clusters running GKE version 1.20 and later, the [kubelet graceful node shutdown feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#graceful-node-shutdown) is enabled by default. The kubelet notices the termination notice and gracefully terminates Pods that are running on the node. If the Pods are part of a Deployment, the controller creates and schedules new Pods to replace the terminated Pods.

During graceful Pod termination, the kubelet updates the status of the Pod, assigning a Failed phase and a Terminated reason to the terminated Pods. When the number of terminated Pods reaches a threshold, [garbage collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection) cleans up the Pods.

You can also delete shutdown Pods manually for GKE version 1.21.3-gke.1200 and later

Delete shutdown Pods manually:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i NodeShutdown | awk '{print $1, $2}' | xargs -n2 kubectl delete pod -n

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep -i Terminated | awk '{print $1, $2}' | xargs -n2 kubectl delete pod -n
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips, nevertheless I am aware of doing it manually, but I was thinking if there's some "more elegant" way, like configuring GKE, to avoid such situation. :)

Comment: I have created a Feature Request on behalf of you can check this link https://issuetracker.google.com/270324871  and follow for updates

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Mayur for creating issue for me. Engineers from Google answered the issue saying it's an intended behavior:

"This is the expected behaviour, pods are cleaned up by K8s Garbage Collector (GC) [1]. The only difference between OSS K8s and GKE here is that the threshold for the GC is different:

OSS K8s: 12500 pods (see --terminated-pod-gc-threshold in [2])
GKE: 1000 or 5000 (for big clusters)
The documentation for GKE has been recently updated to clarify this difference, see [3][4]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection

[2] https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/)

[3] http://cloud/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms#graceful-shutdown

[4] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/spot-vms#termination-graceful-shutdown
I'm closing the bug"

Link to the issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/270324871